# Hiding and Showing keyboard with notificationCenter in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can't get the keyboard to show and hide on my SignUpViewController.

```
//Keyboard frame size
var keyboard = CGRect()

//Default function
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //scrollView frame size
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.height
    scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height

    //check notificvations if keyboard is shown or not
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpVC.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpVC.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: What have you attempted to actually show the keyboard?

Comment: Here you just subscribe for events, not show or hide the keyboard. The keyboard is shown if you tap an text-view for input for example and you get notified by the notification center about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set for example an uitextfield to become the first responder.